# Change the looks of a data frame based on the identical values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
movieId     tag

7099    adventure
7099    anime
7099    ecology
260     fantasy
260     Sci-fi
260     post-apocalyptic
```

Sometimes moviesIDs are the same and I would like to turn it into the data frame that looks like this:

```
movieId tag1      tag2   tag3
7099    adventure anime  ecology
260     fantasy   Sci-fi post-apocalyptic
```

How should I approach this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you always have the same number of tags per movieId?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create **unique rowId** per movie group and then you can use pivot_wider for the purpose.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d %>% group_by(movieId) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number(movieId)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = tag, names_prefix = "tag")
```

output as

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   movieId [2]
  movieId tag1      tag2   tag3            
    <int> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>           
1    7099 adventure anime  ecology         
2     260 fantasy   Sci-fi post-apocalyptic
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful. It didn't work at first but then I removed other columns from the data frame (MovieId and tag columns were between other two columns) and it worked. What could be the reason for that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @NikitaShmygin - when you have more columns and you `pivot_wider` you need to specify what should happen with the columns which you are not pivoting - there is good info on that in the function documentation.

Comment: @NikitaShmygin I wouldn't be able to say exactly unless you share some data. use `dput(your_dataframe_name)`. However, you may try keeping other variables in `group_by()` clause.

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion here ...

I wonder of all movies have necessarily 3 tags. In your approach you would need to create as many `tag` columns as the movie with the most tags - and that might be a bit of a "waste" in terms of many NA's for movies having fewer tags.

I would suggest also a `summarise` version as:

```r
d %>% group_by(movieId) %>% 
  summarise(tags = paste(tag, collapse = "_"))
```

This will "widen" the data frame so that you have one row per `movieId` and all tags (possibly of different number per movie) will be contained in a string in column `tags`.

In your case it will look like this:

```r
  movieId tags                           
    <dbl> <chr>                          
1     260 fantasy_Sci-fi_post-apocalyptic
2    7099 adventure_anime_ecology
```

or use list-columns to keep all tags for a movie in a list

```r
d %>% group_by(movieId) %>% 
  summarise(tags = list(tag))
```

and each list can be of different length depending on how many tags each movie has.

But again it really depends on how you process that data further. So ... just a suggestion for a different way of aggregating the data.

Comment: Thank you! And you are right, not all films have exactly 3 tags.